# Values in function outside of main not being retained in structure

Tags: c, struct

The problem I have is that my values in a function setup up outside of the main is not being retained in the structure. I may not be describing this very well so I will show the program and the results and explain what I want to

```
 struct Satellite
{
    char countries[30];
    int package;
    int priceperpackage;
    int timetransmission; 
    int requestedTransmission;
};

struct Satellite Satellite1;
struct Satellite Satellite2;
struct Satellite Satellite3;
struct Satellite Satellite4;
struct Satellite Satellite5;

void functionInput(void)
{
    /*Country 1*/
    strcpy(Satellite1.countries, "USA");    

    /*Country 2*/
    strcpy(Satellite2.countries, "China");  

    /*Country 3*/
    strcpy(Satellite3.countries, "Germany");    

    /*Country 4*/
    strcpy(Satellite4.countries, "Japan");  

    /*Country 5*/
    strcpy(Satellite5.countries, "Switzerland");    
}

void printItems( struct Satellite satellite );

void assignValues( struct Satellite satellite );

int main(void)
{
    functionInput();

    assignValues ( Satellite1 );
    assignValues ( Satellite2 );
    assignValues ( Satellite3 );
    assignValues ( Satellite4 );
    assignValues ( Satellite5 );

    printItems ( Satellite1 );
    printItems ( Satellite2 );
    printItems ( Satellite3 );
    printItems ( Satellite4 );
    printItems ( Satellite5 );

    return 0;
}

void printItems( struct Satellite satellite )
{
    printf( "%s\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\n",          satellite.countries,satellite.requestedTransmission,satellite.package,satellite.priceperpackage,sat llite.timetransmission);
}

void assignValues( struct Satellite satellite )
{
    satellite.requestedTransmission = (rand()% 2);
    satellite.requestedTransmission = (rand()% 4 +1);
    printf( "%s\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\n",     satellite.countries,satellite.requestedTransmission,satellite.package,satellite.priceperpackage,sate    llite.timetransmission);
}
```

Here is the output

```
USA              4               0               0               0
China            1               0               0               0
Germany          1               0               0               0
Japan            3               0               0               0
Switzerland              1               0               0               0
USA              0               0               0               0
China            0               0               0               0
Germany          0               0               0               0
Japan            0               0               0               0
Switzerland              0               0               0               0
```

Because the same thing isn't printed twice the values from the assignValues function is not being retained in the struct.

Comment: you are doing call by value rather than call by reference so any changes made in the function are only for the function's copy of the struct so any changes made in the function are discarded when it returns.  You will need to pass a pointer of the struct to the function so that when the function modifies the struct it will be modifying the struct in the main().

Comment: I am just beginning so I apologize for my ignorance what is the difference between call by reference and call by value?  Could you please give an example of each?  And how would you pass a pointer of the struct to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```
void assignValues( struct Satellite satellite )
```

should be:

```
void assignValues( struct Satellite *satellite )
{
    satellite->requestedTransmission = (rand()% 2);
```

etc., and you call it by writing `assignValues( &satellite1 );` and so on.  This is how you indicate that you want `assignValues` to operate on the object called `satellite1`.

The way you originally wrote the code, it creates a copy of `satellite1` and sends that copy into `assignValues`. Changes made to a copy do not affect the original.

Comment: That in combination with the information below did the trick thanks!